# C++17 - Modifying const values

Tags: c++, constants

So, as of now, it seems to be impossible to actually modify a "const" value in C++ (tested in VS 2017).

```
const int a = 5;
int* ptr = (int*)&a; // Method 1
*((int*)(&a)) = 6; // Method 2
int* ptr = const_cast<int*>(&a); // Method 3
*ptr = 55;
cout << a << "\t" << &a << endl;
cout << *ptr << "\t" << ptr << endl;
```

Result:

```
5  SOMEMEMORYADDRESS
55 SOMEMEMORYADDRESS
```

Anyone got any idea what else can be tried to achieve the effect? Really curious how it is possible to have 1 memory address (at least according to the console) with 2 values.

Please note: there are topics like this for older C++ versions (and they used to work in the past - but they don't, anymore).

Comment: The impossible is possible. All you have to do is make it so with undefined behaviour.

Comment: This has nothing to do with c++17.

Comment: You're telling the compiler knows `a` is constant, so it assumes that its value won't change. When you output its value with `cout << a`, the compiler actually generates code to pass the value `5` to `cout` instead of the value of `a`.

Comment: This has always been undefined behavior. It might work, it might not, both are within the realm of possibility.

Comment: `std::launder` (C++17-specific) exists precisely so you can reuse pointers to objects containing const members (well, CV-qualified). That being said, you cannot modify a const value. Doing so is strictly UB, avoid it at all costs.

Comment: Solution: `const volatile int a = 5;`

Comment: There are many ways to modify a `const` value.  `const` does not mean "won't change".

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.  You declared `ptr` twice.

Comment: @SidS I am aware of it. The other one was actually commented (originally).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Really curious how it is possible to have 1 memory address (at least according to the console) with 2 values.

It's because you invoked undefined behavior. The C++ standard, from C++98, has expressly forbidden you from modifying an object that is declared `const`. And the standard has a catch-all statement such that if you do *anything* which causes modification of a `const` object, you get undefined behavior.

Because modifying an object declared `const` is UB, the compiler is free to assume that this object will never be modified. So, since the compiler can see that `a` is `const` and it is initialed to `5`, it is 100% valid for the compiler to *at compile time* replace everything which revers to this object with `5`. So when you do `cout << a`, the compiler is free to not bother to access memory; it can just do `cout << 5`.

If you did something to modify the memory behind `a`, that's UB, so the compiler doesn't have to care about what happens in that case.

> they used to work in the past - but they don't, anymore

No, they *never* "worked". They merely just so happened to do what you thought they should. But C++ never guaranteed that compilers would behave in this way, so you have no right to complain about compilers changing that behavior now.